# Parsing a C++ function declaration with Perl 6 grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar, lexical-analysis, raku

I wrote a Perl 6 grammar to parse a C++ function. My final goal would be to parse an entire header. The aim is not to correct C++ syntax errors, but to parse valid C++.

Do you have some advice or improvements?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

grammar FUNCTION {
    token TOP       { [ <attr> \s+ ]? <type> [ \s* <type_mod> ]? 
                        (\s+) <fname> (\s*) "("
                        (\s*) [<parameter> [ "," (\s*) <parameter> ]* ]? (\s*) 
                        ')'(\s*) ';'  
                    }

    token name      { \w+ }
    token namespace { [ "::" ]? [ <name> "::" ]* }
    token attr      { <name>  }
    token type      {  <namespace>? <name> }
    token type_mod  { [ \*|\& ]+ }
    token fname     { <name> }
    token variable  { <name> }
    token parameter { <type> [\s* <type_mod> ]? \s+ <variable> }
}

my $str = "const ::one::std::string ** ma1n( int&& i, two::std::string va1e_ );";
my $parsed = FUNCTION.parse($str);
say $parsed;
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd expect to see many more tests of any program that addresses a problem as gnarly as parsing a C++ declaration.

Choosing a couple I've recently had cause to write (on Stack Overflow), I would immediately add

- ```c++
  void (SENDER::*get_func())(double, double);
  ```

  (from [*Passing pointers to member function as returned values to `QObject::connect()`*](//stackoverflow.com/a/53390003))
- ```c++
  constexpr std::size_t len(const T(&)[length]);
  ```

  (from [*Differentiate between array and pointer as function parameter*](//stackoverflow.com/a/53409160))

Neither of these succeeded when I tried them.

Comment: I've no way to test it right there but I believe it also lacks `noexcept` support